# Spreadsheet like UI and function in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, spreadsheet, django-3.0

So I am trying to build an app in Django with a table in it and I want a part of it to behave like a spreadsheet. The features that I would want to be able to do is

1. Copy Pasting values from google sheet/excel to the UI and vice versa.
2. Automatically add Rows based on the data copied google sheet/excel. For eg: If the table shows 10 rows and the data copied is 15 rows from the Google sheet. Then while pasting in the UI it will automatically add the rows.

**My question is what would be the best way to achieve the above?**

I haven't yet started building the app yet because I want to figure out first how this would work and which tools would do it suitably well and most importantly how can I connect it with Django.

Being a noob to the Django and python (and coding in general) I have been researching this for the past few days and did read articles about this. But haven't found anything concrete. Maybe I am not searching in the right direction. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check https://github.com/trco/django-funky-sheets

Comment: I did see this one. I am confused though is this a free or does it require Handsontable. Sorry if I am coming across as dumb.

Comment: It is a free library but I am not sure about other question, you should check their documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will check it out. :)

Comment: Looks to me like it requires Handsontable.